# Removing clustered index scan even if selected columns are part of index

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, non-clustered-index

Given below script is the simplified example of a situation I am facing -

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(pk bigint IDENTITY(1,1),id bigint, dt datetime)


DECLARE @X BIGINT=1
WHILE (@X<9223372036854775807)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (@X,GETDATE())
  SET @x=@x+1
END

CREATE INDEX idx on #tmp(id,dt)

SELECT id,max(dt) from #tmp  GROUP BY id
```

Execution plan of this SP is scanning created index, how it can be moved to SEEK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query is pulling every row from the table. A scan is going to happen.

Comment: IF the id was duplicate with that index you could have had a loose index scan,but since id is primary key you are stuck wth index scan.Also MAX and GROUP BY are redundant.Maybe you meant `SELECT MAX(id),dt FROM t GROUP BY dt`

Comment: why would you want a seek if you are going through every row of your table?, here a scan is the better way to do it

Comment: Out of curiosity, did anyone try to run it all the way to 9223372036854775807 ? That's going to take ages, no ?

Comment: 9223372036854775807 is overkill, i just wanted to make sufficiently large database. A Scan is expected but would like to see if there is any better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
  (
     pk BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     id BIGINT,
     dt DATETIME
  )

DECLARE @X BIGINT=1

WHILE ( @X < 9223372036854775807 )
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #tmp
      VALUES      (@X,GETDATE())

      SET @x=@x + 1
  END

CREATE INDEX idx
  ON #tmp(id, dt)   /*<-- New*/

SELECT id,
       max(dt)
FROM   #tmp
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text.